# How to run .jar through terminal with more RAM allocated on Mac

Tags: java, macos, terminal

I want to run a .jar program on my Mac from a "bat" file or w/e dont know what it is on Mac.

Why I wan't to do this is because I want to allocate more RAM to the .jar.

Can anyone help out on how to do so? :)

I just want to click on a file and it opens up the .jar file with more RAM allocated automatic.

Answer (score 6):

You need some sort of [shell script](https://supportweb.cs.bham.ac.uk/documentation/tutorials/docsystem/build/tutorials/unixscripting/unixscripting.html). It would look similar to

```
#!/bin/sh
java -Xmx256m -jar /path/to/jarfile.jar
```

The `-XMx` setting determines the maximum amount of RAM the JVM will allocate to your Java program.

See [here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20030728055235121) for how to make this double-clickable from the Mac Finder.

Comment: Hey, yes I know that command. But I just want to create a file to click on so it writes that in automaticly, is it possible?

Comment: So create that shell script, make sure it's executable and you should be able to do that via the Mac Finder. See also my edit above

Comment: Do you have some sort of quick on how to do so?

Comment: This is a clickable file. Just open your text editor and paste the contents in. When you are done, save it (with no extension or .sh extension). Also give executable permission to your file with `chmod u+x`. After that you can double click on your shell script just like you do with .bat files.

Comment: I pasted that in to TextEdit and saved it as "filename" on desktop, how excatly do I do the chmod u+x thingy?

Comment: Open a terminal, cd to your Desktop and type `chmod u+x filename`.

Comment: Did that now, still opens in TextEdit :/

Comment: I don't have access to a OS X box right now, but I guess the problem is either the extension or the way TextEdit is saving your file. Try creating a new file with nano (from your terminal type `nano myshellscript.sh`), paste your contents and give it +x permission.

Comment: Alright, do I paste in what I wrote in TextEdit in the Nano window and then save it? How do I give it +x permission? This is command I'm using btw: #!/bin/sh
java -Xmx256m -jar /Users/John/Desktop/RSBot/RSBot-4025.jar

Comment: It is not working, it just opens up Terminal but after that nothing.

Comment: Is it working when you run `java -Xmx256m -jar /Users/John/Desktop/RSBot/RSBot-4025.jar` directly on the terminal?

Comment: Yes, it's working when I first write java -Xmx256m -jar then drag the jar in. I can also make it work by writing java -Xmx256m -jar java -jar -Xmx1024m RSBot*.jar

Comment: You just need the exactly command that runs on your terminal inside the sh file. Come up with a command that works using full paths like the one above, once you can get it to run in the terminal just paste it inside your sh file and it will work.

Comment: Alright. So wheen i save it from TextEdit do i save it like "filename.sh" or without sh? Because ur first answer u said w/o .sh

Comment: This is what I got now: 

Johns-Mac-Pro:~ John$ /Users/John/Desktop/myshellscript.sh ; exit;
Error: Unable to access jarfile RSBot*.jar

Comment: Yaaay! It's working now!

This made it work: #!/bin/sh
java -Xmx256m -jar -Xmx1024m /Users/John/Desktop/RSBot/RSBot-4025.jar 

Thank you so much Anthony, I have been trying to do this for days now!

Comment: @user1552321 - you appear to have two Xmx settings. Is that right ? Is one of them an Xms ?